# Component does not update after props change with componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component that trigger an modal window when users click on the delete record in the UI,but the problem is that, the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` is only called once,th first time.
For exemple,is i click on the delete Button,the state is updated in the child component that holds the Modal component,the all the other actions after the first one dont trigger Modal show.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class ConfirmationBox extends Component {
  state = { isOpen: false };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: this.props.isOpen });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, nextProps) {
    if (prevProps.isOpen !== this.props.isOpen) {
      this.setState({ isOpen: this.props.isOpen });
    }
  }

  closeConfirmation = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };

  onConfirmDelection = () => {
    this.closeConfirmation();
  };

  onCancelDelection = () => {
    this.closeConfirmation();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal open={this.state.isOpen} basic size='small'>
        <Header icon='delete' content='Confirmer suppression' />
        <Modal.Content>
          <p>Souhaitez-vous vraiment supprimer {this.props.names}?</p>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button onClick={this.onCancelDelection} basic color='red' inverted>
            <Icon name='remove' /> No
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.onConfirmDelection} color='green' inverted>
            <Icon name='checkmark' /> Yes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ConfirmationBox;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to store isOpen in state and in props. Only single source of true is correct way. For example the next way is stored isOpen in props

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class ConfirmationBox extends Component {
  onConfirmDelection = (data) => {
    const { closePopup, confirmDeletion } = this.props;

    closePopup();
    confirmDeletion(data);
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen, closePopup, names } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal open={isOpen} basic size='small'>
        <Header icon='delete' content='Confirmer suppression' />
        <Modal.Content>
          <p>Souhaitez-vous vraiment supprimer {names}?</p>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button onClick={closePopup} basic color='red' inverted>
            <Icon name='remove' /> No
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.onConfirmDelection} color='green' inverted>
            <Icon name='checkmark' /> Yes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ConfirmationBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `componentDidUpdate` method why you have a `nextProps` param if you are using `this.props`

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you don't update the isOpen property in the parent component when trigger closeConfirmation. It just updates the isOpen in the ConfirmationBox state. That's why prevProps.isOpen === this.props.isOpen, they are both TRUE. You should move closeConfirmation to the parent component and use isOpen from props.